# What is the HTML <dialog> tag used for and when to use it?

Tags: html, dialog

The way I've understood it, the tag is used to open and close content like a popup alert. What I fail to understand is what advantages the tag has compared to just using a "div" and styling it with css and adding functionality to it with js. It also seems counter intuitive to manipulate the "open" property in order to show/hide the content instead of using display:none/block; with css.

I also don't understand exactly which scenarios would be considered a dialog box. Is a form login box a dialogbox? What about a popup telling you to disable adblock? Are all popups that can be hidden considered dialog boxes?

Comment: I'm no expert on the Dialog tag, but there's a lot of really good information in the [HTML spec page](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional, hacky way to create a dialog, via designing a `div` via CSS only seems to be intuitive for you because you are used to it. However, you need to implement every functionality related to it, such as:

- opening it
- closing it

Also, in the future, this will be enhanced by standard functionalities, so, while it's not urgent for already existent code, but when you write code, especially when you start a project, it makes sense to start using it. Let's see an example from [Mozilla's page][1]:

```js
var updateButton = document.getElementById('updateDetails');
var favDialog = document.getElementById('favDialog');
var outputBox = document.querySelector('output');
var selectEl = document.querySelector('select');
var confirmBtn = document.getElementById('confirmBtn');

// "Update details" button opens the <dialog> modally
updateButton.addEventListener('click', function onOpen() {
  if (typeof favDialog.showModal === "function") {
    favDialog.showModal();
  } else {
    alert("The <dialog> API is not supported by this browser");
  }
});
// "Favorite animal" input sets the value of the submit button
selectEl.addEventListener('change', function onSelect(e) {
  confirmBtn.value = selectEl.value;
});
// "Confirm" button of form triggers "close" on dialog because of [method="dialog"]
favDialog.addEventListener('close', function onClose() {
  outputBox.value = favDialog.returnValue + " button clicked - " + (new Date()).toString();
});
```

```html
<!-- Simple pop-up dialog box containing a form -->
<dialog id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <p><label>Favorite animal:
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>Brine shrimp</option>
        <option>Red panda</option>
        <option>Spider monkey</option>
      </select>
    </label></p>
    <menu>
      <button value="cancel">Cancel</button>
      <button id="confirmBtn" value="default">Confirm</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>

<menu>
  <button id="updateDetails">Update details</button>
</menu>

<output aria-live="polite"></output>
```

However, at the time of this writing (February the 3rd, 2022), this is not supported in all browsers, so it is perfectly feasible to avoid using it for now, until it will become supported everywhere.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: Now, it is supported in all browsers, except IE, which is going to retire shortly. So, we can safely use `<dialog>` tags.